# what does the {{{ ($site->is_active=="0")? "checked" : "" }} mean in html input radio?

Tags: php, html, laravel, input, attributes

I am beginner with php, recently I came across this `{{ ($site->is_active=="0")? "checked" : "" }}`
inside input radio tag in php file.
I know it is not an attribute neither is it value of some attribute, someone please explain this to me.

```
<input type="radio"  id="option1" name="status" value="0"  {{ ($site->is_active=="0")? "checked" : "" }} >
```

this is actual element structure I am talking about.

Edit : Actually the element is part of Laravel file.

Comment: Seems to me as part of a JS framework such as React, Angular, or Vue. However, it basically is just a **ternary conditional operator** that will apply the `checked` attribute if `is_active == 0` is true. If it is false it will remove it.

Comment: @PeterSmith no actually it is not a part of any JS framework, I encountered this in php file.

Comment: That is no indication that it would not be part of a JS Framework. PHP will parse an HTML Document server-sided which does not exclude Frameworks.

Comment: @tacoshy yeah , actually this is part of php Laravel framework , and this answers my question {{ code }} are used in Laravel to write php code inside (html/html attributes) .

Comment: Agreed, looks like Laravel Blade syntax probably

Answer (score 0):

It is a shorthand for echoing a variable or expression in Laravel Blade. In this case, it's an expression that checks whether `$site->is_active` is equal to `0`.

- If it is, it outputs the string `checked`, which sets the checked attribute of the radio input.
- If `$site->is_active` is not equal to `0`, it outputs an empty string, which does not set the checked attribute.

The shorthand syntax for if-else statements used here is called [ternary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). It has the form :

```
condition ? expression1 : expression2
```

- If condition is true, it evaluates `expression1`
- Otherwise it evaluates `expression2`

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what you answered.